# Sentence breakdown

Tags: clauses, dependent-clause

So I was trying to breakdown this sentence to identify its components into its main sentence and clauses. Here is the sentence:

**Some economists now suggest that home equality loans are merely a new trap to push consumer beyond what is affordable.**

*Source: Longman Complete Course for the TOEFL Test (2001) by Deborah Phillips*

My answer is:

Main sentence: Some economists now suggest that home equality loans are merely a new trap to push consumer beyond what is affordable.

Noun clause 1: that home equality loans are merely a new trap to push consumer beyond what is affordable.

Noun clause 2: what is affordable.

Also, I always try to replace the noun clause in a sentence with pronoun to see if it makes sense. In this case it would look like this:

Main sentence: Some economists now suggest **it** (as a replacement for *that home equality loans are merely a new trap to push consumer beyond what is affordable*)

Noun clause : That home equality loans are merely a new trap to push consumer beyond **it** (as a replacement for *what is affordable*)

Is my answer correct?

Comment: First, you should identify the main **clause**; the whole sentence is already known. Second, you should identify what **type** of subordinate clause each one is. "Noun clause" is right, but one noun clause is a tensed verb complement and the other one is an embedded question that's the object of a preposition. Also, clause 2 modifies clause 1, instead of modifying the main clause.

Comment: @John Lawyer  What do you mean by tensed verb complement and embedded question?

Comment: You have identified the three clauses correctly, though I would give the _that_ clause its proper name of 'declarative content clause', since 'noun clause' is a misnomer. And the _what_ clause is a fused relative clause meaning "that which is affordable". The sentence as a whole is best called the 'matrix clause'.

Comment: @user278175 A tensed verb complement is one type of [complement (Noun) clause](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/complmnt.html). Embedded questions are another type. BTW, BillJ uses a different set of terminology than I do.

Comment: @BillJ@JohnLawyer thanks for the input! Never heard about those before, I'll look them up later...

Comment: There seems to be a mistake in either the original or your transcription.